# Error with Subscript in DialogInput

Tags: string-manipulation, dialog-window, subscript

Writing:

```
DialogInput[DialogNotebook[
  {TextCell["(" <> ToString[Subscript["m", "2"], StandardForm] <> ")"],
   InputField[Dynamic[x], String],
   DefaultButton[DialogReturn[x]]}]]
```

I get:

[image]

and I do not understand how to correct the code.

Comment: `ExpressionCell[..., ShowStringCharacters -> False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid linear syntax (strings generated using `ToString[.., StandardForm]`) and just use normal expressions. For example:

```
DialogInput[
    DialogNotebook[
        {
        Row[{"(", Subscript[m, 2], ")"}],
        InputField[Dynamic[x],String],
        DefaultButton[DialogReturn[x]]
        }
    ],
    ShowStringCharacters->False
]
```